# OleDbException was unhandled, syntax error in WHERE clause?

Tags: vb.net

Having trouble with a persistent error. My form allows the user to see a list of elements in a particular group. The input for group number is a combobox called groupbox and the output is a combobox called ElementResults. I am getting the error on the line: GroupSearch.ExecuteNonQuery()

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class ElementsSearch
Public Shared connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data        Source=C:\Documents and Settings\A\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\A2\Element.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Public Shared ElementsTable

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim Search As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Search.Open()

    Dim SearchCriteria As String
    SearchCriteria = Groupbox.Text
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * From ElementsTable WHERE Group='" & SearchCriteria & "'"
    Dim GroupSearch As New OleDbCommand(query, Search)
    GroupSearch.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = GroupSearch.ExecuteReader()
    ElementResults.Text = Convert.ToString(reader("Name"))

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you start with debugger and paste what is coming in `SearchCriteria`?

Comment: Why do you execute the command twice? Remove `GroupSearch.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Im quite new to vb, and this was modified from a teachers example. I have removed the line you highlighted, but I still get an error: InvalidOperationException No data exists for the row/column. This error occurs on the line "elementresults.text = Convert.ToString(Reader("Name")

Comment: I'm not surprised, see my answer, but accept `Patrick Hofman's` answer as this solved you're initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the field `group` which is a reserved keyword.

Try `[group]` instead like in this sample:

```
SELECT * From ElementsTable WHERE [Group]='aaa'
```

Comment: Ahh I should have thought of the reserved keywords. Your suggestion solved my error, but now I have a new one: InvalidOperationException No data exists for the row/column. This error occurs on the line "elementresults.text = Convert.ToString(Reader("Name"))

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all the errors you're getting, consider changing your code to something like this:

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Using command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * From ElementsTable WHERE [Group]=@Group", connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", SearchCriteria)
        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader.Read()
                ElementResults.Text = reader.GetString("Name")
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```